# Nativescript vue remove zoom button on WebView

Tags: nativescript-vue

I'm new in NativeScript.
I can't remove the zoom button from webView. Usually, I didn't find any way of resolving this problem.

```
<Page id="webViewID" class="page" @loaded="onWebViewLoaded($event)">

export default {
    methods: {
                onWebViewLoaded(event) {
                    console.log("Hi can I hendle to event for remove zoom");
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it on  as in your case. You need to have @loadFinished on webview

```
<WebView src="url"
    @loadFinished="finished"
/>
```

and in your methods

```
methods: {
    finished(args) {
        args.object.android.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    }
}
```